# Snaplogic - Using both mapValue and mapKey functions in the mapper snap

Tags: mapper, snaplogic

I have documents from salesforce that contain fields with a suffix of '__c' and the dates are formatted in UTC.  I want to format the incoming data using the mapValue and the mapKey functions to remove the suffix and make all fields lower case AND format the dates into US/Eastern timezone.

I cant get the code to do all that I want: I have the following configuration:

```
$.mapKeys((value, key)=>key.endsWith('__c')
  ? key.replace('__c','').toLowerCase()
  :key.toLowerCase())
    &&  
 $.mapValues((value, key) => key.toLowerCase().search("createddate") >=0 && value !=null
  ?  Date.parse(value).toLocaleDateTimeString({"timeZone":"US/Arizona"})
   :value)
```

This logic formats the dates but not the columns  If I reverse it the columns are formatted and not the dates.  Same thing if I change the && to ||.  How can I get both transformations?  Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked

$.mapKeys((value, key)=>key.endsWith('__c')
? key.replace('__c','').toLowerCase()
:key.toLowerCase()).mapValues((value, key) => key.toLowerCase().search("createddate") >=0 && value !=null
?  Date.parse(value).toLocaleDateTimeString({"timeZone":"US/Arizona"})
:value)